# Django QuerySet is too redundant

Tags: python, django, api, dry

So I have an issue simply for my own sanity...I have made an API, but it is extremely redundant since the same operations need to be done on multiple different objects:

```
def seen_by(self,user):
    return self.filter(seen__user=user)
def created_by(self,user):
    return self.filter(created__user=user)
#and the list goes on
```

For the API, the names will always have words be separated by an underscore and have the word of the table I need to get to as the first word. **Is there any way to make it so I don't have to be so redundant?**

Comment: Are you sure you need these methods in the first place? Perhaps the clients can call `queryset.filter` directly?

Comment: these are simplified, some are 6+ lines that will be used a lot, so a method for it is useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question now, so:

```
def field_by(self, field_name, user):
    return self.filter(**{field_name + '__user': user})
```

Comment: Okay that is cool, but in reality I am using filter and traversing through multiple relations so this does not actually help. I will change the way the question looks to be more clear

Comment: that is a very clever hack. I was thinking about doing something like that, but I forgot I could flatten a dictionary to keyword args

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to create an abstract model and have your models inherit it.

```
class Base(models.Model):
    def seen_by(self, user):
        return self.seen.get(user=user)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class ChildModel(Base):
    ...
```

Comment: this does not fix my problem...these are in a custom query set so it is put into every model without repetition...I do not like the redundancy of having to do such a similar function for 10+ tables in the database, I feel like I should only have to write it once